# Oracle PL/SQL Cursor in Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, cursor

I got this trigger, seems to be alright but i got the error :

Trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TABLE_BI
BEFORE INSERT
ON TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    CURSOR cur_list IS
        SELECT emp, name, day, salary, id,phone
        FROM TABLE NATURAL JOIN OTHERTABLE
        WHERE emp = :NEW.emp AND name = :NEW.name AND id = :NEW.id;

    curChoice cur_list%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    OPEN cur_list;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_list INTO curChoice;
        EXIT WHEN cur_list%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(curchoice.id);
        dbms_output.put_line(curChoice.emp);
        dbms_output.put_line(curchoice.name);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_list;

END;
/
```

I got those error :

```
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.emp'
```

If i remove the ':' in the cursor declaration in my WHERE clause, i got a lot more error

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose you're using some editor which thinks that :new.emp is its variable.  Turn off variable binding then

Comment: Just taking a step back to elucidate the debugging pricess in such cases. Always try to `COMPILE` your code in `SQL*Plus` and then use `SHOW ERROR` to see the error stack. It will be very useful. You would save a lot of time while debugging the error in your `PL/SQL` code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the error, in my cursor declaration in the WEHRE clause, i had to remove

```
emp = :NEW.emp AND name = :NEW.name
```

because there's no such column in the table that im currently inserting.

Thank !